# For two single irrational numbers "a" and "b" if (a+b) or (a-b) is rational , will it always be "0"?

Tags: irrational-numbers

As per me the above statement should be true since if the sum of two irrational numbers is 0 , it implies that two irrational numbers must be like +k and 
-k  where k is an irrational number . Also when diffrence of two irrational numbers is rational it is possible only when both the irrational numbers are same . From both the above cases we can conclude that if sum of two irrational numbers is rational  or difference of two irrational numbers is rational then it must be 0 . Please correct me if I am wrong . By "a" and "b" I mean single or individual irrational numbers for example only "pi" and not "pi +/- something" .

Comment: Your title talks about the sum *and* difference being rational, but the body talks about the sum *or* difference being rational.  These are very different.  The body is longer, so seems to be what you are asking about.  Please clarify.

Comment: $\implies$ and $\Leftarrow$ are not the same thing.  If $x + k =0$ then $k=-y$ is $k$ irrational.  So if the some of an irrational and a number is $0$ the other number is irrational.  That's $\Leftarrow$.  That that WASN'T the question.  The question was if $x$ is irration and $y$ is irrational but $x + y=q$ is rational is $q$ equal to $0$.  That's $\implies$ and the answer is no.  Take $x = \pi$ and $y = 2-\pi$.  Both are irrational and $x + y = 2$ which is rational but not $0$.

Comment: "if the sum of two irrational numbers is 0" That was not the hypothesis so it is not relevent.  The hypothese was the sum of the two irrational number is *rational*.  There are other rational numbers than just $0$...."Also when diffrence of two irrational numbers is rational it is possible only when both the irrational numbers are same"  Nonsense!  If $x - y = 2$, then does that mean $x$ and $y$ must both be rational?  What if $x = \pi$?  Then $y = \pi-2$.   $\pi$ is irrational.  Does that mean $\pi-2$ must be rational?

Comment: @fleablood symbolically by "a" and "b" I mean single irrational number , that is , for example , only "pi" and not "pi - 2" . I do have sense just forgot to clarify what I mean

Comment: $\pi -2$ is a single irrational number.  How do you distinguish between   $3.1415926535897932384626433832795....$ being a "single irrational number" but $\pi -2 = 1.1415926535897932384626433832795...$ is not?  Are you saying $1.1415926535897932384626433832795...$ doesn't count? Isn't really irrational?  Doesn't exist on its own?  What?  In any event $3.1415926535897932384626433832795...$ is irrational.  And $1.1415926535897932384626433832795...$ is irrational.  And $3.1415926535897932384626433832795...-1.1415926535897932384626433832795... = 2$

Comment: Note:  $x + y = k\iff x = k-y$.  So distinguishing between $x$ as an irrational number and $k-y$ as "not a single irrational number" doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: OK you win , i was wrong thanks for your valuable time and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overthink it.

If $x$ irrational then $q - x$ is irrational for every rational $q$.

So $x + (q-x) = q$ is the rational sum of two irrational numbers.  But $q$ can be any rational number and doesn't have to be $0$.

=====

This is one of those results that when you analyze it you realize it can't actually *mean* anything.

We think.  $rational + rational = rational$

And $rational + irrational = irrational$.

But what of $irrational + irrational$ can that be rational.

Well, $\sqrt 2 + (-\sqrt 2) = 0$ and $0$ is rational so it can be rational.

So we think... and we say... Yeah, but $\sqrt 2$ and $-\sqrt 2$ are related to each other, they are negatives of each other.  I bet if you have two *independent* irrationals the must add to a irrational.

So someone else says well if $x +y = k$ and $k$ is rational, then if $x$ is irrational then $y= k - x$ is irrational and $x + y = x+(k-x) = k$. so that is two irrationals that add to a rational.

So we say... but those are *dependent* to each other; I bet if you have two *independent* irrationals the must add to a irrational.

So the other person asks.  How exactly to you define if two irrationals are "dependent"?

And we say... well if $x$ is irrational and $y = \pm x + k$ for some rational $k$ they are dependent.  So I claim that if $x,y$ are independent than $x + y$ is not rational.

And then other person says.... so in other words, you are claiming that there is no rational number $k$ so that $y =\pm x + k$ then $y \mp x \ne k$ for any rational $k$ but if there *is* such a rational $k$ so that $y =\pm x + k$ then $y\mp x$ *might* be rational; is that what you are claiming?

And we say, yes, now how can I prove it?

And the other person says.  Um... you just said $x \mp y =k; k$ rational if and only if $x = \pm y +k$ for some rational $k$.  Do you really think that is meaningful?

And we say.... Ulp, I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

If $a+b$ and $a-b$ are both rational, then so is $a$ since it is the average of those two quantities, and the average of two rational numbers is also rational. Thus also $b=(a+b)-a$ is rational.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement in the body is not correct.  For example, both $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 2 +1$ are irrational.  Their difference is $1$, which is rational.  If both the sum and difference of two numbers are rational, the two numbers must be rational, but that is not what your question says.

Comment: i have edited my question.